# Label names to each data points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, label

I have a set of data I am analyzing and I would like some help if you can. My data consist of two columns but my X column is only one point and my Y column is about 50 points . So when I plot it of course it's just just diff points along the Y axis versus one single point on the x axis.
Now those points are really closed to each other and what I would like to do is to label each point to their actual Channel name. But so far I tried to use the `text()` function an it gives me an error saying that my x and y value should be the same. I'm not sure which way to do this anymore. Keep in mind that I have the names of each data points in a file also. Can you help? Keep in mind using one x value and 50 Y values. Lets say I fix it and now the names are on top of each other. Is there a way I am space them out without affecting the location of the points.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do with text and the error message you receive?  Also, do you need to plot the x value or could you simply plot the y values and put the channel label along the x axis?

Comment: Sounds like you want to change the `XTickLabels` property of your plot: `set(gca,'XTickLabel', names)` where `names` is a cell array of strings containing your names.

Comment: I fixed the labeling problem but now My data points are too closed to each other that The labels are all on top of each other... But they follow the same display pattern as the data points.... the ones that are on top of each other are because the points are on top of each other...what can I do to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, but apparently the main problem is to zoom in on few specific points that are overlapped and to make sure that they all fit inside the grid. But every time i try to play with the Yaxis( using Ytick, and axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax]) and zoom(), i can see the ones that are overlapped all spaced out but the other ones end up outside the grid. I used Ytick and Xtick with set(gca, 'Ytick', ' ') but that stopped the text function from working and disabled the labels. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dan Let's just say you have as straight line that constitutes of points. and there are 50 points on that line but some of them are so closed to each other that they look like they overlap. YOu and all of them to clearly appear on the line. when you zoom in on the overlapped ones the other points get out of the axis range. but what you really want is to be able to zooom in on the overlapped ones and make them appear clearly and not affect the visibility of the other ones. That way a good copy of the figure can be taken.

Comment: So then you have two choices, use subfigures to display the close points on a zoomed in axis and all the points on a zoomed out axis. Or plot them against `f(x)` instead of `x`, i.e. find a suitable transformation function like `log(x)` or something